# How to disable -werror while building edk2?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, edk2

I'm trying to investigate UEFI and EDK2. I have found some labs to learn it (https://laurie0131.gitbooks.io/uefi_driver_hii_win_lab_guide/content/).

In this guide talks that I must add my project to Nt32Pkg.dsc and turn off -Werror in Conf/tools_def.txt.

Firstly, I haven't any mentions of Nt32Pkg in edk2 source code which I have cloned from https://github.com/tianocore/edk2. So I have created task in VS2019 to run edk2 Emulator:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskLabel": "build-emulator",
      "appliesTo": "/EmulatorPkg",
      "type": "launch",
      "contextType": "build",
      "command": "BuildEmulator.bat",
      "args": [
        "-b DEBUG"
      ],
      "output": "${workspaceRoot}\\Build\\EmulatorX64\\DEBUG_VS2019\\X64\\WinHost.exe"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "clean-emulator",
      "appliesTo": "/EmulatorPkg",
      "type": "launch",
      "contextType": "clean",
      "command": "BuildEmulator.bat",
      "args": [
        "-b DEBUG",
        "-b RELEASE",
        "clean"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "build-payload",
      "appliesTo": "/UefiPayloadPkg",
      "type": "launch",
      "contextType": "build",
      "command": "BuildPayload.bat",
      "args": [
        "-b DEBUG"
      ],
      "output": "${workspaceRoot}\\Build\\UefiPayloadPkgX64\\DEBUG_VS2019\\FV\\UEFIPAYLOAD.exe"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "release-payload",
      "appliesTo": "/UefiPayloadPkg",
      "type": "launch",
      "contextType": "custom",
      "command": "BuildPayload.bat",
      "args": [
        "-b RELEASE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "clean-payload",
      "appliesTo": "/UefiPayloadPkg",
      "type": "launch",
      "contextType": "clean",
      "command": "BuildPayload.bat",
      "args": [
        "-b DEBUG",
        "-b RELEASE",
        "clean"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-edk2",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "type": "launch"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-edk2",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "type": "launch"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-EmulatorPkg",
      "appliesTo": "EmulatorPkg/",
      "type": "launch"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-EmulatorPkg",
      "appliesTo": "EmulatorPkg/",
      "type": "launch"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-EmulatorPkg",
      "appliesTo": "EmulatorPkg/",
      "type": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have added my project to EmulatorPkg.dsc like:

```
   MyWizardDriver/MyPkg/MyWizardDriver/MyWizardDriver.inf{   
    <LibraryClasses>    DebugLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDebugLibConOut/UefiDebugLibConOut.inf 
        }
```

Now I can build Emulator with my project, but I have an error:
error 12288: CHAR16 : unexpected token
in struct:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct {

    UINT16  MyWizardDriverStringData[MYWIZARDDRIVER_STRING_SIZE];
    UINT16  MyWizardDriverHexData;
    UINT8   MyWizardDriverBaseAddress;
    UINT8   MyWizardDriverChooseToEnable;
    CHAR16  *MyWizardDriverNvRamAddress;  //bug is here
} MYWIZARDDRIVER_CONFIGURATION;
#pragma pack()
```

I'm also haven't any mention -Werror in Conf/tools_def.txt.

So, how can I disable -Werror in my build? Or what am I doing wrong?

Full error trace:

```
VfrCompile...
C:\edk2\EmulatorPkg\MyWizardDriverNVDataStruc.h(21): error 12288: CHAR16
unexpected token

VfrCompile...
MyWizardDriver.vfr(11): ERROR 12288
undefined

VfrCompile...
C:\edk2\EmulatorPkg\MyWizardDriver.vfr(13): error 12288: MWD_IfrNVData
undefined

VfrCompile...
MyWizardDriver.vfr(11): ERROR 12288
undefined

VfrCompile...
C:\edk2\EmulatorPkg\MyWizardDriver.vfr(23): error 12288: MWD_IfrNVData
undefined

VfrCompile...
C:\edk2\EmulatorPkg\MyWizardDriver.vfr(23): error 12288: MWD_IfrNVData
can not use the efi varstore like this

C:\edk2\EmulatorPkg\VfrCompile : error 0003: Error parsing
compile error in file c:\edk2\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\MyWizardDriver\MyPkg\MyWizardDriver\MyWizardDriver\OUTPUT\.\MyWizardDriver.i
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um\winspool.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um\prsht.h
C:\edk2\EmulatorPkg\NMAKE : fatal error U1077: C:\edk2\BaseTools\Bin\Win32\VfrCompile.EXE :   "0x2"
Stop.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared\pshpack8.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared\poppack.h


build.py...
C:\edk2\EmulatorPkg\EXEC : error 7000: Failed to execute command
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe /nologo tbuild [c:\edk2\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\MyWizardDriver\MyPkg\MyWizardDriver\MyWizardDriver]


build.py...
C:\edk2\EmulatorPkg\EXEC : error F002: Failed to build module
c:\edk2\MyWizardDriver\MyPkg\MyWizardDriver\MyWizardDriver.inf [X64, VS2019, DEBUG]
```